# After all, which the difference between string[] | number[] and (string | number)[]?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, union

I was looking for some codes on github and I found some interfaces with

```js
interface A {
  type: string[] | number[]
}
```

and others like

```js
interface A {
  type: (string | number)[]
}
```

But, whitch the difference?

Comment: First allows only homogenous arrays like `[1,2,3]` or `["a","b","c"]`, the other additionally allows mixed like `[1,"a",2,"b"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is "an array of strings or an array of numbers".  In which the array can contain strings *or* numbers, but not a mix of both.

The second is "an array of strings or numbers".  In which the array can contain strings, numbers, or a mix of both.

Consider them structurally as:

```
(an array of strings) or (an array of numbers)
```

and

```
an array of (strings or numbers)
```